# Watson Knowledge Studio annotating addresses

Tags: nlp, ibm-cloud, watson, watson-knowledge-studio

I am trying to create a machine learning model in WKS and am currently in the process of annotating documents. I want the model to extract address entities. My broader goal is to understand an author's intent to switch their mailing address from an old address to a new one. The challenge is that there will be two or more mentions of an address in the text and the model needs to distinguish between the two.
I have seen examples where each piece of the address is treated as a discrete entity

I.E.

- [735] [Airport Rd], [Bismarck], [ND] [58504]
  entities: street number, street name, city, state, zip

-VS-

- treating the entire address as one entity
  [735 Airport Rd, Bismarck, ND 58504]
  entity: address

the reason I would want to treat the entire address as one entity is because I need the model to distinguish between the **old address** and the **new address** I believe if I treat an address as one entity then I can use the relationship between the identifying clause such as:

- new address: [new_address] or, the new address is [new_address]

Has anyone tried to do something similar in WKS or with another NLP tool?
Is it possible to treat each piece of the address as an entity and define a relationship between each piece of the address and old_address/new_address respectively?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to define **Address** entity type and annotates multiple tokens as an address mention. WKS does not restrict a mention to a single token (but too long mention annotation is not recommended)